# The BPS mass formula for 3d N=4

Tags: quantum-field-theory, research-level, supersymmetry, yang-mills

Is the mass formula (or equivalently the central charge formula) known for BPS particles in 3d $\mathcal{N}=4$ susy gauge theories?

In particular, what is its dependence on the Fayet-Iliopoulos parameters, and real mass parameters?